# IntelliJ and Symlink cycles

Tags: intellij-idea, symlink

My build step involves creating symlinks to javascript folder.
It seems that everytime I reopen the project in IntelliJ it always fails to load the project if I had not deleted the symlinks before closing it. Discovered this after wasting numerous hours! Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to *not follow* symlinks or maybe ignore certain folders?

BTW. Why symlinks? So that while I am testing/developing I can make source code changes and that reflected right away. During deployment instead of symlinking I can copy files (and perform minification + optimization).

Comment: Do you really need to use symlinks? Any reason why this can't be accomplished with for example maven profiles and jrebel?

Comment: Most probably it's a bug so please [file an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com). As a workaround you may try to replace recursive symlinks with more linear ones.

Comment: @vikingsteve, for historic reasons while the build system is maven, this is not a Java project so JRebel is not an option

Comment: @RomanShevchenko, well linearization is possible but a bit of work. But yeah I think I'd rather spend some time ensuring cycles won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

So, the situation was, we were inside an environment where npm was not available. And what I needed was something akin to npm link. Taking up Roman's advice, I decided to spend sometime and ensure no cycles exist.

Transitive dependencies made it a bit of work to detect cycles.